# Displaying grid column wise using jquery templates

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-templates, jsrender

I have data in json row wise for plans.. 
like

```
[{"CostPerSearch":2.39,"PackageId":9,"PackageName":"PAYG","PackPlanId":1,"PackTypeId":2,"SearchPerMonth":0,"SetupFee":349.00,"SubscriptionFee":0.00,"ValidityMonth":null},{"CostPerSearch":1.99,"PackageId":10,"PackageName":"Standard","PackPlanId":1,"PackTypeId":2,"SearchPerMonth":275,"SetupFee":349.00,"SubscriptionFee":499.00,"ValidityMonth":null},{"CostPerSearch":1.79,"PackageId":11,"PackageName":"Premium","PackPlanId":1,"PackTypeId":2,"SearchPerMonth":600,"SetupFee":349.00,"SubscriptionFee":999.00,"ValidityMonth":null},{"CostPerSearch":1.59,"PackageId":12,"PackageName":"Silver","PackPlanId":1,"PackTypeId":2,"SearchPerMonth":1500,"SetupFee":349.00,"SubscriptionFee":1999.00,"ValidityMonth":null},{"CostPerSearch":1.39,"PackageId":13,"PackageName":"Gold","PackPlanId":1,"PackTypeId":2,"SearchPerMonth":3800,"SetupFee":349.00,"SubscriptionFee":4999.00,"ValidityMonth":null},{"CostPerSearch":0.00,"PackageId":14,"PackageName":"Platinum","PackPlanId":1,"PackTypeId":2,"SearchPerMonth":0,"SetupFee":349.00,"SubscriptionFee":9999.00,"ValidityMonth":null}]
```

I want to display above data column wise as below format

```
Packages        PayG       Standard .......

Setupfee         349         349
Monthlyfee       0           499
......
```

I have json but confused about jquery template usage to display column wise data easily in above look.

Comment: You could use [jqGrid](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/commits/master)

Comment: Is there any sample using jquery template? Because I have data row wise and want to display column wise.

Comment: If you want to repeat your data horizontally, you can produce all your HTML as a collection of divs and apply CSS formatting to stack them sideways like 'float: left' . Please note that 'float: left' will force all you content towards left only if the parent container has enough space left. Otherwise you will have to make the parent container horizontally scrollable to show all content.

Answer (score 0):

One choice would be to just transform the javascript object before dropping into the template.  It appears that you know how many rows the table will have.  In your sample, it has 8 rows since each entry has 9 attribute but you are going to pull out one for the top column name.

That kind of transform, while a little tedious, isn't rocket science.

You could also look at the "stars" example.  It appends a string for each rating.  The way that it applies here is you can have a set of string -- 9 in this example.  One for the header one and then 8 more for each of the data rows.  In the each loop, append a {{:PackageName}} to the header string and a similar (for example) {{:SetupFee}} to the setup_fee string.  Once you are done with the strings, wrap the tr string with a  string.  wrap each td string with a "tr" and then wrap all those with a "tbody".  Finaly wrap the two in a table.